# User defined procedure timeout

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-plugin

How can I implement a timeout mechanism for my [neo4j user-defined procedure](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/procedures-and-functions/procedures/)?

My code is simply this.

```
@Procedure(value = "nameOfMyProcedure", mode = Mode.WRITE)
@Description("finds the minimal sub-graph from given nodes")
public Stream<Output> nameOfMyProcedure(@Name("p1") Long p1, @Name("p2") Long p2, ...) {
    // there are some codes here. I want to make a timeout mechanism for codes inside here
}
```

I tried using `java.util.concurrent.Callable` and `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`

```
AdvancedQuery that = this;
Callable<Output> receiveResponse = () -> {
    // put all the codes inside this callable
    return output;
}

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Output> future = executor.submit(receiveResponse);
Output result = null;
try {
    result = future.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    log.info("Completed successfully");
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    log.info("unexpected error: ", e.getMessage());
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    log.info("Timed out. Cancelling the runnable...");
    future.cancel(true);
}

executor.shutdown();
if (result == null) {
    return Stream.of(new Output());
}
return Stream.of(result);
```

I get this `ExecutionException`

> org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge$BridgeNotInTransactionException:
> The requested operation cannot be performed, because it has to be
> performed in a transaction. Ensure you are wrapping your operation in
> the appropriate transaction boilerplate and try again.

Comment: Is `receiveResponse` performing its DB operations inside a transaction?

Comment: It is not updating. It only traverses nodes and edges to bring a sub-graph

Comment: Even if you are only reading from the DB, your operations must be performed in a transaction.

Comment: I'm just using neo4j API like `db.getNodeById()` or `node.getNeighbors()` etc...